# Why did he reject my thank you?

Tags: phrase-meaning, politeness, negation, emphasis, prosody

I know "No, thank you" means rejection.

> Me: Hey, Bob. You want some drink?
>
> Bob: No, thank you.

But I was involved with this kind of conversation

> Me: Thanks, Mr Jordan for teaching me.
>
> Mr.Jordan: No! Thank **you**!

Did he reject my thanks? Does this mean that it's something like *No Problem*, or is he trying to say that *I'm the one who should thank you!*. Or has he had enough of me? He has taught me for 5 years, so we have a good relationship (I hope).

Comment: I think your response would better be written: Mr. Jordan: No! Thank **you**. Emphasis is on the **you**. @StoneyB's answer is correct. It is a very pleasant response to receive.

Comment: The "*no*" means "*No need to thank me.*" Mr Jordan is thanking ***you*** for the opportunity to teach you (or whatever).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

He is saying that you don't owe him thanks, he owes *you* thanks. He clearly regards you as the sort of student who makes teaching rewarding. He may even imply that he has learned from you, from the sorts of questions you have asked which made him think about things which he took for granted.

Comment: +1.  In some sense, he is rejecting your thanks (by suggesting it was not necessary to thank him) but this is not rude; it is a concept that shows up in many polite responses to thanks: "Don't mention it."  "No problem."  "It was nothing."  It doesn't really mean that you shouldn't thank them or that they don't appreciate your thanks.

Comment: You can think of his response in much the same way another common exchange: "It was a pleasure meeting you." response: "No, the pleasure is all mine". @stoneyb is correct, your teacher thinks it is him who should thank you for being such a great student. The pleasure was all his.